# SQL filtering from more tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need your help with my MySQL query.

There are table products, parameters.

Table parameter_values = here are all possible values for single parameter.

Table product_parameters where is assigned product to parameter (product can have more different parameters). Structure: product_id, parameter_id

And table product_parameters_values - some products have allowed only some parameter values. Structure: product_id, parameter_id, parameter_value_id

And now - on front-end is selector, where I can check values of parameters and I need to select products with this conditions: (e.g. I selected parameter id 1 - with values 50,51 | and parameter ID 2 with values 60,61).

- all product must have assigned all selected parameters, so in product_parameters must be 1 and 2 in our case.
- parameters values are empty (not specified allowed parameters, so all values are possible) OR
- if parameter values not empty then must contain at least one of value for each parameter

Now I have this, for select all products which have all parameters assigned and :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT p.* FROM (
        SELECT products.* FROM products
            INNER JOIN products_parameters ON products_parameters.product_id = products.id
            WHERE products_parameters.parameter_id IN (1,2)
            GROUP BY products.id
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT products_parameters.parameter_id) = 2
        ) AS p
        LEFT JOIN products_parameters_values AS ppv2 ON ppv2.product_id = p.id 
                AND ppv2.parameters_options_id IN (51,61)
        GROUP BY p.id, ppv2.parameter_id
) AS p2 
GROUP BY p2.id HAVING COUNT(p2.id) = 2
```

But I don´t know how to add condition OR product_parameters_values is empty for tested parameter (so all values are possible). Or is possible to simplify the query above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.parameter_id), ppv.parameters_options_id, p.* FROM (
    SELECT products_parameters.parameter_id, COUNT(ppv.parameter_id) AS total, products.* FROM products
        INNER JOIN products_parameters ON products_parameters.product_id = products.id
        LEFT JOIN products_parameters_values ppv ON ppv.parameter_id = products_parameters.parameter_id AND ppv.product_id = products.id
        WHERE products_parameters.parameter_id IN (7,9)
        GROUP BY products_parameters.parameter_id, products.id) AS p
        
LEFT JOIN products_parameters_values AS ppv ON ppv.product_id = p.id AND ppv.parameter_id = p.parameter_id AND ppv.parameters_options_id IN (58,38) 
WHERE total = 0 OR ppv.parameters_options_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.parameter_id) = 2
```

Maybe that can be simplified, but this is only solution what works for me.